# Using stored procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I want to learn to use a stored procedure in php and for some reason it does not work

This is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `counter`(INOUT `inc` INT)
    DETERMINISTIC
SET inc=inc+1$$
DELIMITER ;
```

written in phpmyadmin

I want to make a loop that increments a value for each row in a result from another query:

```
$nr=0;
  $query2="Call counter(?)";


echo '<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Nr pereche </th>
    <th>Id 1 </th>
    <th>Id 2</th>
 
  </tr>';

while($result->fetch()){

  $result1 = $connect->prepare($query2);
  $result1 ->bind_param("s",$nr);   
  $result1->execute();
 

  echo '<tr><td width="30%">'.stripslashes($nr).'</td>';
  echo '<td width="30%">Chestionar  '.stripslashes($r1).'</td>';
  echo '<td width="30%">Chestionar '.stripslashes($r2).'</td></tr>'; 
}
```

[what is currently displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtN1m.png)

In the first column, it should be 1,2,3 not 0,0,0.

I know that it can be done much easier but I want to use a stored procedure. Thanks

Comment: it does not work because you didn't research how to use a stored procedure in php but just wrote some code off your head, that would never work

Comment: I actually did but really didn't find that question. Problem solved. Thank you anyways